# Is it Ok to lock or unlock my suspension fork while riding?

Tags: suspension

When I need to switch the suspension fork, should I stop before switch?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you should generally stop and set the suspension to an uncompressed/unloaded position before you switch, especially if it's a cheaper lockout.

Similarly, you would not try to change the position of a deadbolt on a door while the door is partially open.

See [Do I need to take my weight off the bike to lock out the suspension?](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/14730/do-i-need-to-take-my-weight-off-the-bike-to-lock-out-the-suspension)

Answer (score 1):

Hydraulic lockouts can be activated on the fly.

Mechanical ones can't (in theory), because you the fork has to be completely extended. I can activate my mechanical lock on the fly by pulling up on the stem with one hand and turning the lock with the other hand, but it's a little dangerous:)

All forks can be unlocked on the fly.

Answer (score 0):

You can just switch while riding along.  Obviously, (assuming no bar mounted remote) you have to be going at a speed at which it's sensible to take one hands off the bars to open/close the fork.  If you forget to unlock the fork and head down a descent you might want to stop/slow down a lot to switch it in that case.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you have a bar-mounted lockout, there is of course a small risk involved in taking a hand from the bar, bending down and flicking the lockout, but other than that I can't see it being detrimental to the bike in any way.

All the lockouts I've tried require the weight to be off the fork though which usually necessitates a slight front-end lift to allow the lockout to be turned, so you probably have to account for that.

I certainly wouldn't do it in any kind of tricky terrain, or when travelling at speed, but I lock mine out or re-enable all the time on the move.

Answer (score 0):

I'd assume it's something you could, but you probably shouldn't do. Kind of like shifting a car into gear without being stopped, you're just gunna wear your hardware that much faster.