# what is difference between remote lockout and hydraulic lockout?

Tags: fork, suspension, front

hey does anybody know if a hydraulic lockout can be used with a remote?

like if a bicycle has an option of remote lockout.

does that mean the remote has been added to mechanical or hydraulic lockout?

its confusing as the remote lockout itself is not a type of lockout but just a remote added to an existing lockout technology like hydraulic or mechanical. but which one of the two is it is what i wanna know

Comment: Is English a second language as this question is hard for me to follow?

Comment: from the tags, it's a front suspension fork with lockout, and there's a [hydraulic option with some forks](http://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/14730/do-i-need-to-take-my-weight-off-the-bike-to-lock-out-the-suspension). We have an answer to 'how does that work', and I think it's probably a dupe

Answer (score 2):

Remote as a general term means "controlling from a distance".

From that perspective it can work with either hydraulic or mechanical lockout. It is a separate entity to the lockout and is just a way of controlling it from, say the handlebars.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I'm aware, remote lockout is only compatible with a hydraulic lockout system.

A mechanical lockout requires the fork to be completely extended in order to lock it, which is generally not the case when you're on the bike.